# How to check a specific value in a 1x4 double Cell using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, compare, cell, combinations

If I have a 4x1 Cell structure with :

```
[1x4 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x4 double]
[1x4 double]
```

And each Cell has :

```
[5,3,0,0]
[0,3,5,0]
[1,3,0,0]
[0,3,2,0]
```

**I would like to do the following :**

Pick cells that have the first array a value = 5

ans : `[5,3,0,0]`

Pick cells that have second array a value = 3

ans :    `[5,3,0,0]    [0,3,5,0]    [1,3,0,0]     [0,3,2,0]`

etc

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
a = cell(4,1);
a{1} = [5 3 0 0];
a{2} = [0 3 5 0];
a{3} = [1 3 0 0];
a{4} = [0 3 2 0];

findval = 3;
arrayind = 2;

b = a(cellfun(@(x)x(arrayind) == findval,a));
b{:}
```

terminal:

```
ans =

     5     3     0     0


ans =

     0     3     5     0


ans =

     1     3     0     0


ans =

     0     3     2     0
```